# android studio delete file from vcs

Tags: git, version-control, android-studio

I'm looking for to exclude a file form versioning.
I see the "add" to vcs button on a file but i doesn't find the "untrack" or "ignore" button like in eclipse.I tried to exclude folder .idea/. I tired to edit gitignore manualy and the ignore file button but nothing works.
Any ideas ?

Thanks 
thomas

Comment: see the git help for .gitignore

Comment: this is my gitignore :
.gradle
/local.properties
.DS_Store
/build
.idea/
app/app.iml
*.iml

Comment: As comment this is not readable. Put it in the question.

Answer (score 44):

You can remove tracked files from vcs manually using "Terminal" tab in Android Studio or Git Bash console.

To untrack ignored files you should:

1) Make sure the files you want to ignore are properly listed in .gitignore

2) Commit pending changes (important!)

3) Execute commands

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
```

4) And then commit again:

```
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

These steps will remove all the items from Git Index and then update it again, while respecting git ignores.

The reason for commiting pending changes at step 2 is that if the rm is part of another commit it doesn't work as expected.

Check more information in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/2858969).

Comment: "git add ." adds all the files not just in .gitignore

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to untrack unwanted files